# Angular 4 Translation on electron desktop app

Tags: angular, plugins, electron, desktop-application, ngx-translate

Im developing an electron desktop application with Angular 4. I need to add the translation feature in it with some language options. What is the best method to add translation (like plugin or ngx-translate) both performance wise and a better approach. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you mean language localisation using angular? This may help you: https://medium.com/@sstarx/language-localisation-using-angular-9-a6f8ee8cfc08

Comment: Yes language localization